# PHP - Reading contents of another PHP file without it echoing

Tags: php

I am trying to reach the contents of a PHP file without the file actually outputting what it would usually do. Here is my test code:

File1 (test1.php)

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    include_once './test2.php';
    $test = ob_get_contents();

    echo $test;
?>
```

and here is file2 (test2.php)

```
<?php
     $testVar = 'Name!';
?>
<div class="testClass"><?php echo $testVar?></div>
<p>Spam2</p>
```

and I want it to only do this because of the

echo $test

line NOT because the file is outputting the content.

```
<p>Spam2</p><div class="testClass">Name!</div>
<p>Spam2</p></body>
```

due to the echo, but it returns this

```
<p>Spam2</p><div class="testClass">Name!</div>
<p>Spam2</p></body>
<p>Spam2</p><div class="testClass">Name!</div>
<p>Spam2</p></body>
```

So how do I get it to only return the content once?

Comment: Where are 2 files ??? You need two files . 1.Actually contains some content. 2.This php file Reads content from other file . Please be clear.

Comment: if your'e going to check your code.

you write the word "Spam" to the php file.

and in the same php file you are getting the content of the same php file. and echo it.. Please elaborate the question

Comment: I want the file to only say "Spam" once. Meaning the $test variable is the only container that has Spam. I don't know how else to word this. It would lead up to what I actually want to do, but I break things down before I go more complicated.

Comment: Show code on `./test2.php`.

Comment: I did, right below the test1.php. Instead of Spam, I would include HTML or such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't `echo $test;`. PHP is executing as it should. Since `./test2.php` shows Spam in HTML it appears on the page, then you assign the page contents to a variable and `echo` it. What do you expect?

Comment: I explained what I expected. I want to get what the file is outputting and take that into a variable and then use it. I don't want it to output AND put it into a variable. I didn't ask whether or not it is performing correctly, I asked how to make it do something other than what is happening.

Comment: You don't have to output the file if you use `file_get_contents()`. `ob_get_contents()` is for output buffering to get contents of the current page. You don't even need to `ob_start()` unless you want to output buffer your code. When you include or require a file it goes right into the file which you included it into.

Comment: Wel, you are helping me by getting my question to where it needs to be. I updated once again, sorry. How I had the rest of my project setup was that it took the contents and returned it within JSON, but I guess that switching over to just HTML itself, no JSON, would alleviate this problem and make other sectors of the topic easier. Instead of this, I will change how I mean to use this data. Thanks for the help in pushing me toward this direction :P. My actual question can remain unanswered.

Comment: Glad it's working out. Lately I'm using PHP more and more to produce JSON to use with JavaScript. AJAX, AJAX, AJAX.

Comment: Haha, yeah. That's why I wanted it to work the other way, but this just as fine :P.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 files say: `app/index.php` and `app/config.php` you can just use the `return` keyword to return some content from the config.php file. And then, when you include the file whatever you returned from config.php can be saved to a variable.

Example:

First return whatever you want from the config.php file (could be an array, string, etc).

```
<?php 
return ['name' => 'Spam'];
```

Then in the index.php:

```
<?php
$contents = include_once('config.php');
echo $contents;
```

Comment: Ok there are two ways one is just include the file and you get the desired output like so: `<?php include_once './test2.php'; ?>`. The other one if you must save the contents to a variable for whatever reason. Is to call `ob_end_clean()` before the `echo`.